# What is expected from a Master's thesis, especially contrasted with a Bachelor's or PhD thesis?

Tags: soft-question

I'm thinking of enrolling in a Master's degree  in Mathematics and it culminates with a thesis rather than being purely course-based. I am wondering what is expected of students writing a Master's thesis and how it compares to a Bachelor's/PhD thesis. For my Bachelor's thesis, a literature review was sufficient. How much (if any) original research and results are required in a Master's thesis? I expect that it varies by country but I am still interested in expectations in all different countries, not just limited to my country (Netherlands).

My specific program is in applied mathematics, and the thesis is supposed to written over one semester (4-5 months).

Comment: Similar questions asked on Academia.SE:
   (1) [What are the main differences between undergraduate, master's, and doctoral theses?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7252/)   (2) [What is expected in a masters thesis of a mathematics student?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/69317/)

Comment: If you want answers specific to your case, you might also want to mention how much time is dedicated to working on the thesis in your programme (just summer months or an entire academic year), and whether your topic is pure/theoretical or applied/computational, as expectations may vary depending on these.

Answer (score 3):

I'm in my final master year, preparing my masters thesis in Stochastic Analysis, Algeria.

We didn't have any Bachelor thesis.

As for the masters thesis: We're expected to analyse an article or a concept (Girsanov's theorem, BSDE's, etc). The evaluation is based on how good can the student write, organize, and plan his work, how can he analyse what the concept/article is about, can he find any flaws or contradictions, can he provide his own point of view about it. That's all for the moment.

Sometimes student can find new original ideas while preparing their masters thesis. It all depends on them at that time.

Best of luck !